# Can I restore wallet which do not have any transactions yet?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, mnemonic-seed, wallet-recovery

I just created new Monero wallet and want to test if I can restore it with my 25 words seed. However, it always yields me error. What might be problem here?

Comment: "However, it always yields me error" <- Perhaps you could update/edit your question with the details of the error.

Comment: It just says: Failed to restore wallet with mnemonic seed.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is you didn’t
Use the same application to create this mnemonic. I would advise you to convert this to a compatible one but why complicate things?

The purpose of your test is to see if you can restore the wallet so make a new
Wallet and restore on another device/operating system. Problem solved.

Be sure they are both same releases. And you can use this strategy when recovering your wallet in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should try restoring a wallet from another seed, one that is guaranteed to be valid (just peruse answer on stack exchange). Maybe you just copied the seed or typed it incorrectly? If there's a typo, then of course the wallet will throw an error.

Try restoring the seed below. DO NOT USE THIS AS YOUR WALLET SEED. Restore height can be the latest block or 0 if you want to test the time it takes to do a full restore.

nanny loudly nouns spout joining money peaches imagine lottery ladder natural navy bomb duplex hydrogen oatmeal domestic apart utmost odometer gourmet cucumber haunted hurried gourmet